# How to approach this issue with django

Tags: django, authentication, https

I just started of in Django and want to implement this. But not sure whether my approach is correct or not. Can you validate?

Requirement : My Server will provide a service via an url endpoint. Client will authenticate (with id and password supplied to him via separate channel. So, no signup page available) with his credentials and avail the service. i will do the work asynchronously and reply with status.

My Approach.
. Client will be provided a username and password via separate channel. 
. Client will do an https connection. 
. Client will encrypt the password with my public Key and will call my URL endpoint with id, password, data.
. i will acknowledge the request and will ping client back when the work is done.

Things i am worried about:
. how to stop snoopers from replacing the data portion and reforwarding the request to me.
. how to stop snoopers from reusing the encrypted password from original request and sending their own request.

Are there any frameworks which will provide this support inbuilt? 
OR
This will not occur at all in my current setup?

I know Django provides an authentication module. But not sure about its capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework will help you enable security at an application level.  You can use Django to help you ensure that only users that have been properly authenticated will be granted access to restricted pages and provides a number of [other security measures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/) out of the box.

[Replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) will typically be prevented by using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), which is well documented by Django.

Based on the description of your implementation, the greatest source of concern would be the statement "**client will be provided a username and password via separate channel**".

Comment: Hey. thanks for clarifying. the separate channel is manual. as i don't have too many clients and i am not expecting to scale in near future. it does not make sense for me to make it automatic atleast for now.

Comment: No problem.  If you feel this answer is correct, go ahead and indicate it as the correct answer, as a way of closing this posting.